# Power Bi Embedded A1. questions?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

i have some doubts, please help:

1. If the service (pbi embedded) is running from 8.00 am to 18.00 pm per day, but my users just use the
   reports from 9:00 am to 11:00 am (then nobody use it). Do i have to pay 10 hours or 2 hours?.
2. Can i schedule when to pause and when to restart the pbi embedded service on azure?
3. I have like 30-40 users, and 40-50 reports, is the A1 license enough?
4. Can i schedule when to use A1 and then A2?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You are paying for the time when the service runs. So in this case - you will pay 10 hours.
2. You can use [Suspend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi-embedded/capacities/suspend) and [Resume](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi-embedded/capacities/resume) API calls. This can be easily done, e.g. with a PowerShell running on [Azure Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/learn/automation-tutorial-runbook-textual-powershell). [Save on Your PowerBI Embedded Capacity](https://www.drewsk.tech/2019/12/26/save-on-your-powerbi-embedded-capacity/) is a good one to start with. I'm copying the sample code from the article below for a reference.
3. It depends on your reports and how active are your users. But start with A1 and scale up if necessary. Start with [Capacity planning in Power BI embedded analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embedded-capacity-planning) and [Deploying and Managing Power BI Premium Capacities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/guidance/whitepaper-powerbi-premium-deployment) to get more information.
4. You are free to scale up or down. One of the Microsoft's examples shows how you can do that - see [Zero-Downtime-Capacity-Scale.ps1](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/powerbi-powershell/blob/master/Zero-Downtime-Capacity-Scale.ps1) (it is too long to copy it here).

   ```
   workflow pbi-embedded-suspend-resume
   {
       Param
       (
           [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
           [String]
           $AzureResourceGroup,
           [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
           [String]
           $PowerBIEmbeddedName,
           [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
           [Boolean]
           $Suspend
       )
       $connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"

       try
       {
           # Get the connection
           $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName

           "Logging in to Azure..."
           Connect-AzAccount `
           -ServicePrincipal `
           -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
           -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
           -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint
       }
       catch {
           if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
           {
               $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
               throw $ErrorMessage
           } else{
               Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
               throw $_.Exception
           }
       }

       #checking if the PowerBI Embedded Capacity Exisit
       $IsPBEmbExisit=Test-AzPowerBIEmbeddedCapacity -Name $PowerBIEmbeddedName

       if($IsPBEmbExisit -eq $true)
       {
           if($Suspend -eq $true )
           {
               try
               {
                   #Suspending the Service
                   "Suspending $PowerBIEmbeddedName started"
                   $SuspendOperation = Suspend-AzPowerBIEmbeddedCapacity -Name $PowerBIEmbeddedName -ResourceGroupName $AzureResourceGroup -PassThru
                   "$PowerBIEmbeddedName is Suspended Successfully"
               }
               catch
               {
                       Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
                       throw $_.Exception
               }
           }
           else
           {
               try
               {
                   #Resuming the Service
                   "Resuming $PowerBIEmbeddedName"
                   $ResumeOperation = Resume-AzPowerBIEmbeddedCapacity -Name $PowerBIEmbeddedName -ResourceGroupName $AzureResourceGroup -PassThru
                   "$PowerBIEmbeddedName Resumed Successfully "
               }
               catch
               {
                       Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
                       throw $_.Exception
               }
           }
       }

       else
       {
           "The Provided Resource $PowerBIEmbeddedName doesnot exist"
       }
   }
   ```